# Its ok for postgres database performance to split a long function, in multiples function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

We just introduce a new plpgsql function into our database, giving us a way to determinate some index based in a business flow that is critical for us. But this code have to many lines (48 lines) and is hard to read. My partners suggested me to split this long function into small functions. For me was an OK suggestion, to make it more readable, we do this in all our code. But I am not sure is this will impact the database performance.

Thanks in advance,

Btw this function, just don't laugh... But I will appreciate any suggestion

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_base_in_business_flow(line_uniq_code TEXT, line_customer_code TEXT, exception_name TEXT, filter TEXT,scope_published BOOLEAN) RETURNS INT AS $$
DECLARE
process_id int := 0;
count int := 0;
request_filter TEXT;
BEGIN
IF filter = 'ALL' THEN
  request_filter := '%';
ELSE
  request_filter := '%'|| filter || '%';
END IF;
  SELECT special_request.process_id INTO process_id FROM special_request JOIN request ON request.id = special_request.process_id WHERE special_request.supplier_db_ref = line_customer_code AND request.published=scope_published AND request.name LIKE request_filter;
  GET DIAGNOSTICS count = ROW_COUNT;
  IF count != 1 THEN
    SELECT request.id INTO process_id FROM request WHERE request.name LIKE request_filter AND request.published=scope_published AND request.db_ref = (SELECT replace(line_customer_code, reference_replacements.name_used_by_buyer, reference_replacements.name_used_by_supplier)  FROM reference_replacements WHERE line_customer_code ~ reference_replacements.name_used_by_buyer);
    GET DIAGNOSTICS count = ROW_COUNT;
    IF count != 1 THEN
      SELECT uniq_code_request_relations.process_id INTO process_id FROM uniq_code_request_relations JOIN request ON request.id = uniq_code_request_relations.process_id where uniq_code_request_relations.uniq_code = line_uniq_code AND request.published=scope_published AND request.name LIKE request_filter;
      GET DIAGNOSTICS count = ROW_COUNT;
      IF count != 1 THEN
        SELECT request.id INTO process_id from request where request.name LIKE request_filter AND REGEXP_REPLACE(request.db_ref,'[^0-9A-Za-z]','') = REGEXP_REPLACE(line_customer_code,'[^0-9A-Za-z]','') AND request.published=scope_published;
        GET DIAGNOSTICS count = ROW_COUNT;
        IF count != 1 THEN
          SELECT request.id INTO process_id from request where request.name LIKE request_filter AND REGEXP_REPLACE(request.db_ref,'^0+','') = REGEXP_REPLACE(line_customer_code,'^0+','') AND request.published=scope_published;
          GET DIAGNOSTICS count = ROW_COUNT;
          IF count != 1 THEN
            IF exception_name = 'USE_REGEX' THEN
              SELECT request.id INTO process_id from request WHERE request.name LIKE request_filter AND REGEXP_REPLACE(request.uniq_code,'^0+','') LIKE (REGEXP_REPLACE(line_uniq_code,'^0+','') || '%') AND request.published=scope_published;
            ELSE
              SELECT request.id INTO process_id from request WHERE request.name LIKE request_filter AND REGEXP_REPLACE(request.uniq_code,'^0+','') = REGEXP_REPLACE(line_uniq_code,'^0+','') AND request.published=scope_published;
            END IF;
            GET DIAGNOSTICS count = ROW_COUNT;
            IF count != 1 THEN
              process_id := 0;
            END IF;
          END IF;
        END IF;
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN process_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: perhaps you should share this "long" function, so that we can take a look.

Comment: Yes it will impact performance a lot more than, say, doing the same in a compiled language. Also depends on how much data is being passed in parameters etc. I've done a fair bit of performance testing with PG, and where performance is critical we just inline everything to get rid of the significant overheard of calling functions.

Comment: I just add the code, my plan was to split every element between an if statement as new function. As you see, I tried to keep it as some Text and a boolean value.

Comment: This bit: `GET DIAGNOSTICS count = ROW_COUNT;
  IF count != 1 THEN`, are you specifically interested in `1` or do you just want to know if it was found?

Comment: In the business logic that was passed to me, it said that if the count of returned value is different to one, skip the result and tried the next one.  So we can't have 2 request_code as a result, so i tried to performance this using DIAGNOSTICS

Comment: Well I don't know if it's more performant, but you can get rid of the `count` variable and replace the two line `GET DIAGNOSTICS/IF count` with `IF NOT FOUND THEN`. 1 is irrelevant in this case because `SELECT INTO` without `STRICT` will never select more than 1, so `count` will always be 0 or 1, and therefore you may as well use the already available `FOUND` variable.

Comment: +1 I will give it a try, and see if  test plan  complete all in green. But I don't but split into function is still a concern to me....

Comment: I wouldn't split it if performance is a concern. I guess it depends how it's being run. Thousands of times in a loop? Once here and there? Then again, there are probably better places to find improved performance - for example, you're doing two very similar queries on `request` - you could probably restructure that part to hit that table once only, and save more than you'd lose by splitting the function.

Comment: Also consider sql vs plpgsql - I still don't quite understand it, but in some cases I find SQL functions to be much more performant, even when called from a plpgsql function, and other times they're slower, even though they're just doing a simple query. So you could try splitting it if you want, make the splitted out functions SQL, run it in a loop 1000000 times, then change them to plpgsql and run the loop again and see the  difference. And see the difference with keeping them all in the same function.

Comment: About how many its called, its called twice for every request line, and our average per transaction is around 1000 request line per transaction.  
I will take notes of your advice, that will help me a lot. I will do some test, to see what happen

Comment: I personally think that your function is readable and not too long. If performance is a concern, PL/pgSQL is not the first choice, and other stored procedure languages might do better. Also, regular expressions are bad for performance.